# Lombok not compiling an abstract generic superclass

Tags: java, compiler-errors, lombok

I have this class:

```java
@SuperBuilder
public abstract class EventFinder<EventType> {
    private final String accountId;

public abstract List<EventType> find();

    public static abstract class EventFinderBuilder<C extends EventFinder<?>, B extends EventFinderBuilder<C, B>> {
        public B accountId(String accountId) {
            log.trace("Account ID: %1s".formatted(accountId));
            this.accountId = accountId;
            return self();
        }
    }
}
```

Been trying to make `@SuperBuilder` work with it but to no avail,
I'm overriding some of the builder methods to include logs, which works great,
Compiling outputs:

```
error: wrong number of type arguments; required 2
@SuperBuilder
^
```

I can do it just fine by removing the abstract method from the class and simply implementing it in the subclasses, but I would like to declare it here as this is the parent.

Tried to play with the @SuperBuilder parameters, nothing helps, tried to remove the abstract method, which worked, but did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your class has generic type parameters, The builders that lombok generates will also have those type parameters. The builders are static classes, and so the `EventType` type parameter of `EventFinder` is not in scope in the builder classes.

If you want to write your own implementation for a part of the code that Lombok generates, the signature has to match exactly. You should declare the `EventType` type parameter too.

```
public static abstract class EventFinderBuilder<
    EventType,
    C extends EventFinder<EventType>, 
    B extends EventFinderBuilder<EventType, C, B>
> { ... }
```

But as rzwitserloot said in their answer. This kind of defeats the purpose of Lombok. If you are adding a log for every field in your class, you might as well handwrite the entire builder yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As the docs of `SuperBuilder` explain, you can't handwrite parts of the builder. It's way too complex, which is why you can't do it.

if you absolutely insist, remove the handwritten `EventFinderBuilder`, throw the result through delombok (`java -jar lombok.jar delombok`), study that *very* carefully, and then handroll things. And be aware it's not recommended. In the end wanting the complications of builders that can build across a type hierarchy with custom bells and whistles exceeds the lombok target of "make boilerplate less annoying" because it's no longer boilerplate at that point.